# How can I add multiple arrays to a JComboBox?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jcombobox

I am making a theatre seat bookings system for some coursework but am having trouble on creating a JComboBox to help the user select a seat from the set of 197 that there are altogether.

The seats are represented by "Seat" objects which are merely a collection of a few variables such as "isBooked" (Boolean). The seats are arranged into multiple seat arrays, each array represents a row of seats e.g. A[], B[]...

For the booking of the seats, having the seats separated by row was necessary as they have different prices, however the JComboBox will be used as a way of selecting a seat to unbook and hence just a full list of seats is required.

I can easily add a single array to the JComboBox and have it work fine but an attempt to add any more arrays to the list in the JComboBox fails.

How can I add multiple arrays to the JComboBox?
i.e. A[1], A[2], A[3]... A[14], B[1], B[2]...

I am not very experienced in Java so sorry if this is a stupid question.
After lots of research over the past few days, I have tried experimenting with the DefaultComboBoxModel class but am obviously not using it correctly. This was my most recent attempt to solve my problem:

```
DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
            model.addElement(A);
            model.addElement(B);
            model.addElement(C);
            model.addElement(D);
            model.addElement(E);
            model.addElement(F);
            model.addElement(G);
            model.addElement(H);
            model.addElement(J);
            model.addElement(K);
            model.addElement(L);
            JComboBox seatCombobox = new JComboBox();
            seatCombobox.setModel(model);
            unbookSeatWindow.buttonsPanel.add(seatCombobox);
```

All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Your DefaultComboBoxModel code is the correct answer.  You just add elements from as many arrays as you have.

May I suggest that you use two JComboBox components.  One for the section, and another for the seat number.  Otherwise, your users will get frustrated reading a list of hundreds of seats.

Comment: If someone is "unbooking" a seat, I would try to provide them with only those seats that they **have** booked, rather than a list of every seat in the place, most of which are not relevant.

Comment: @rcook: I missed that line in the question.  Yes, when unbooking, only show the seats the person booked.

Comment: So the code I put is correct? Why doesn't it work then? All that shows is a random sequence of numbers in place of each array in the JComboBox when I use this code. I love the two combo box idea too, I will get familiar with my old setup to begin with and then investigate doing this, thanks.

Comment: @Mike: Assuming A, B, C, etc. are elements, yes.  You'd probably want to put the addElement method calls in a for loop, one for loop for each array.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Sorry for the stupid question, but... What exactly is an element? Is a Seat[] an element? Is this why it isn't working, because a Seat[] isn't an element?

Comment: @Mike: Seat[] is an array of Seat instances.  Make sure Seat has a toString method.  The output of the toString method is what's displayed in the combo box.  Each Seat instance is an element.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc yep, the Seat class has a toString method this was advised to me by somebody else who was helping me although I didn't actually understand why I was told to do it. As all of this seems to be fine, I still cannot figure out why the JComboBox isn't working then. This is the result when I use my code: http://pasteboard.co/1eej5Be1.png

Comment: @Mike: This has to be the last comment from me.  The toString method in Seat has to return the String that represents your seat number.  You're returning the default Object string.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc ok, thank you for your help. I have set the toString method to return a String representing the seat but it still doesn't work. I'll keep debugging.

Answer (score 3):

You can fill the model in following way using `ArrayList`:

```
    DefaultComboBoxModel model ;
    JComboBox seatCombobox = new JComboBox();
    public void fillModel()
    {
      ArrayList<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();
      elements.addAll(java.util.Arrays.asList(A));
      elements.addAll(java.util.Arrays.asList(B));
      elements.addAll(java.util.Arrays.asList(C));
      elements.addAll(java.util.Arrays.asList(D));
      elements.addAll(java.util.Arrays.asList(E));
      elements.addAll(java.util.Arrays.asList(F));
      elements.addAll(java.util.Arrays.asList(G));
      elements.addAll(java.util.Arrays.asList(H));
      elements.addAll(java.util.Arrays.asList(I));
      elements.addAll(java.util.Arrays.asList(J));
      elements.addAll(java.util.Arrays.asList(K));
      elements.addAll(java.util.Arrays.asList(L));
      model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(elements.toArray()) ;
      seatCombobox.setModel(model);
    }
```

Comment: I thought Vectors were outdated and not meant to be used any more.