# Why can't I add multiple arrays to my JComboBox?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface, jcombobox

I am making a theatre seat bookings system for some coursework but am having trouble on creating a JComboBox to help the user select a seat from the set of 197 that there are altogether.

The seats are represented by "Seat" objects which are merely a collection of a few variables such as "isBooked" (Boolean). The seats are arranged into multiple seat arrays, each array represents a row of seats e.g. A[], B[]...

I can easily add a single array to the JComboBox and have it work fine but an attempt to add any more arrays to the list in the JComboBox fails. I can add the seats one at a time but this is obviously going to be inefficient.

How can I add multiple arrays to the JComboBox? i.e. A[1], A[2], A[3]... A[14], B[1], B[2]...

This is the code for my JComboBox at the moment and, as far as I can see, this should work - I cannot figure out why it isn't. I have a method in the Seat class called toString() which returns the String representing the seat.

```
DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
            model.addElement(A);
            model.addElement(B);
            model.addElement(C);
            model.addElement(D);
            model.addElement(E);
            model.addElement(F);
            model.addElement(G);
            model.addElement(H);
            model.addElement(J);
            model.addElement(K);
            model.addElement(L);
            JComboBox seatCombobox = new JComboBox();
            seatCombobox.setModel(model);
            unbookSeatWindow.buttonsPanel.add(seatCombobox);
```

The result of this code is this: http://pasteboard.co/1eej5Be1.png
In the JComboBox is the random code (I forget the name of this) representing each array, but nothing to represent each individual seat in the array. In total, there should be 197 entries in the JComboBox

All help will be appreciated.

As suggested, I tried using

```
`allSeats = ArrayUtils.addAll(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, J, K, L);`
```

but NetBeans told me to change this to

```
`allSeats = (Seat[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, J, K, L);`
```

NetBeans then said that everythign was alright but as soon as I tried to run the program, I got this exception:

> BlException in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Cannot store java.lang.Object in an array of Seat     at
>   org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils.addAll(ArrayUtils.java:3469)  at
>   BookingsSystem.main(BookingsSystem.java:267) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ArrayStoreException     at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native
>   Method)   at
>   org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils.addAll(ArrayUtils.java:3459)  ...
>   1 more Java Result: 1

line 267 is the line above

Comment: May be - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708289/add-the-contents-of-an-array-to-a-combo-box

Comment: @joeyrohan OP wants to add contents of multiple arrays to combo box

Comment: @Apurv I think the question is answerd : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644063/how-can-i-add-multiple-arrays-to-a-jcombobox

Comment: @joeyrohan DUPLICATE !!!

Comment: @Mike don't ask same question _again and again_, you already asked same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644063/how-can-i-add-multiple-arrays-to-a-jcombobox)

Comment: Ok can you do this?take a single string insted of multiple arrays?Then there can be a way.

Comment: @Apurv The last question didn't result in solving my issue and this question lead to completely different responses as I have updated it with more information.

Comment: What is the _type_ of `A`, `B` etc, and `allSeats` ?

Comment: @Apurv, They were all Seat[]. I have found the solution as being only adding two parameters at a time (Therefore using the addAll() several times).

Comment: @Mike It is good that you solved your problem, but I think you should think on a different approach as [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644063/how-can-i-add-multiple-arrays-to-a-jcombobox) to you. You should visit popular ticket booking site and try to implement in the way they do.

Comment: The find of @Mike, although perhaps the wrong approach to his question, is a great question in itself.  Why does addAll fail on > 2 arrays and succeed on 2 arrays thus forcing one to string together addAll calls?  Is it because casting has to be performed at each step in the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine arrays using the method suggested by @Apurv.

```
Seat[] seats = ArrayUtils.addAll(A, B, C);
```

Create your JComboBox like this:

```
JComboBox seatCombobox = new JComboBox(seats);
```

This will create a new JComboBox using a default model and the first item selected

Comment: hehe well are you sure there is no other way?Like this OP have to use n loops for n array's.

Comment: You're right no need to explicitly loop through, looked up JavaDoc for JComboBox to find there is a constructor that takes an array.

Comment: Netbeans isn't recognising ArrayUtils

Comment: It's part of the Apache Commons library.
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

Comment: @flight2039 that's great, thanks. I've downloaded and installed it into Netbeans. By any chance do you know what the import statement is for ArrayUtils?

Comment: hhmmm... that didn't seem to work. Please see the edit in the question.

Comment: I managed to sort it. Still using this answer but only having two parameters at a time meaning I use it several times.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ArraysUtil.addAll()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28T%5B%5D,%20T...%29) to combine all the arrays to one and then add the single array to `JComboBox`

Comment: Netbeans won't recognise Arraysutil

Comment: Download Commons-lang jar from [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi).

Comment: That didn't seem to work. Please see the edit in the question.